# Is the <label> element outdated?

Tags: html, tags, label, w3c

I’ve searched everywhere and I can’t find an answer... is `<label>` an outdated HTML element?

Comment: Well the best place to look is in the w3 standard specs. Following this link, http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-label-element, you will find it in HTML5 draft.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't. It's even in HTML5: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-label-element.

EDIT:

What gave you that idea?

Comment: I thought I read it on w3 yesterday but i wasnt entirely sure and couldnt find it again... lol ty for the response

Comment: Sigh.  Don't provide a link to W3 Schools; they have nothing to do with the HTML specs.  Provide a link to actual spec.  Here's the link to the current editor's draft, which includes the label element:  http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-label-element.